# Javascript - Flood hazard map

Tags: javascript

I have a big data (4 million lines) with XYZ format. I want to draw a map like this http://en-gb.topographic-map.com/places/Ho-Chi-Minh-City-6643171/

Tried heatmap.js (data too big) and plot.ly countor map (cant zoomin) but cant use. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at [google heatmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap)

Comment: do you have another plugin ? because i'm using my own API to draw my map, all i want is something to draw a overlay over my map.

Answer (score 1):

In your example it is not heatmap but overlaying image that is being generated by API on http://wms.ess-ws.nrcan.gc.ca webside. Here is what it looks like in example's site js.

```
Map.mapTypes.set('Toporama', new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(Coordinates, Zoom) {
            Copyrights.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.nrcan.gc.ca" target="_blank">&copy; Natural Resources Canada</a>';
            var Projection = Map.getProjection();
            var Factor = Math.pow(2, Zoom);
            var Bottom = Projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(Coordinates.x * 256 / Factor, (Coordinates.y + 1) * 256 / Factor));
            var Top = Projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((Coordinates.x + 1) * 256 / Factor, Coordinates.y * 256 / Factor));
            return 'http://wms.ess-ws.nrcan.gc.ca/wms/toporama_en?layers=WMS-Toporama&format=image/png&srs=EPSG:4326&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&styles=&bbox=' + Bottom.lng() + ',' + Bottom.lat() + ',' + Top.lng() + ',' + Top.lat() + '&width=256&height=256';
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        name: 'Toporama (Canada)',
        minZoom: 6,
        maxZoom: 20
    }));
```

It might be also an answer to you if you can use or create similar API for your data. In my opinion such big data shouldn't be processed by browser.

Comment: You are spot on with the overlay image but the OP might want to visualize flood hazard and not altitude. Do you have any approach that will take OP's data and generate an image?

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
My problem is, i have a geoTIFF file, i converted it to XYZ file with x is lat, y is lon and z is height which decides color. I have my own API to draw map, so i want to draw an overlay from my data above to overlaying my map.

Comment: @Martin Gottweis, seems YodaVN is using his own API so it's hard to suggest anything without getting into it.

Comment: @YodaVN, what do you mean by having your own API to draw map, what technology are you using? Have you tried to modify geoTIFF file with heatmap data?

Comment: could be this in any help [Link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15095/how-to-display-a-geotiff-image-with-openlayers-at-the-right-place). Thought you could modify it in map generation process as raster image.

Comment: @MikeKor true that ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all the help @MikeKor